# What is the best format to return array in JSON response?

Tags: arrays, json

I'm asking about the best practice to return data array in a JSON response...

Like this :

```
{ myObjectContainsArray: [ {object1}, {object2}, {object3}] }

// and get it like this => myObjectContainsArray[0].object1property
```

Or :

```
[{object1}, {object2}, {object3}]
// and get it like this => [0].object1property
```

What is the best way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a potential cross-site vulnerability when returning plain arrays, described here: https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

> It turns out that a script that contains a JSON array is a valid
>   JavaScript script and can thus be executed. A script that just
>   contains a JSON object is not a valid JavaScript file. For example, if
>   you had a JavaScript file that contained the following JSON:
>
> ```
> {"Id":1, "Balance":3.14}
> ```
>
> And you had a script tag that referenced that file:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://example.com/SomeJson"></script>
> ```
>
> You would get a JavaScript error in your HTML page. However, through
>   an unfortunate coincidence, if you have a script tag that references a
>   file only containing a JSON array, that would be considered valid
>   JavaScript and the array gets executed. [..]

Therefore it's recommended to only return objects.

Comment: This is largely a non-issue these days: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#corb

Comment: Thanks a lot, have a nice day :)